# Change value of check box when its name is the value of a variable

Tags: excel, vba

First post so I'll try my best to make it a good one (please tell me if I'm doing it wrong).I can't seem to write the code properly to change the value of a check box or option button on a sheet using a variable.

Suppose the name of the check box name is "Chk1", normally I would write :

```
Worksheets("AP-1").Chk1.value=X
```

Where X is (either True or False). Since it is a Loop, I use a range variable called FoundRange and it's value is the name of the check box, so I tried:

```
dim chkname as string
chkname=foundrange.value
Worksheets("AP-1").Chkname.value=X
```

I also tried

```
Worksheets("AP-1").CheckBoxes(chkname).Value = X
```

and

```
Worsheets("AP-1").Shapes(chkname).ControlFormat.Value=X
```

I also had a linked cell that I used to change the value, but when it writes either false or true in it, the check box becomes gray and I need to press F2+Enter in the linked cell to make the check box show the proper value. I also tried to select the linked cell after changing its value and use that code:

```
Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

but it did not work.
Please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your initial code, it must be an ActiveX control, not a Form one, so:

```
dim chkname as string
chkname=foundrange.value
Worksheets("AP-1").OLEObjects(Chkname).Object.value = X
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was sure I had tried this one too, but I must have made a mistake. Thanks Rory!